# Distribution and pdf of sum of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The independent variables $X$, $Y$ have binomial distributions with parameters $m$, $p$ and $n$, $p$, respectively. Find the pdf of $X + Y$ . What distribution does $X + Y$ have?

Can somebody give me some ideas, please?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts.  do you know [characteristic function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialDistribution.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use any numbers of anything fancy. Use words and an understanding of what they mean. What does it mean for $X \sim B(n,p)$ ? It means $X$ takes the value of however many time an event $E$ occurred in $n$ trails where each event occurs with probability $p$. $Y$ is nearly the same thing its just we now have $m$ trails.  Hence the variable $X+Y$ is asking us: " In $n+m$ trails how many times does $E$ occur where the chance of $E$ occurring each trail is $p$ "  This is clearly another binomial distribution with $n+m$ trails and probability $p$

Hence $X+Y \sim B(n+m,p)$

FYI this isnt a "PDF" it is a "PMF" as it is discrete not continuous

Comment: You *may* also do it with symbols, if you wish. Start with $\mathsf P(X{+}Y{=}k)=\sum_{i=0}^k\mathsf P(X{=}i,Y{=}k{-}i)$ and make use of the Vandermonde identity: $$\binom{m+n}k=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom mi\binom n{k-i}$$ $\tiny\text{Of course, Vadermonde proved this identity using a similar counting argument to oskar szarowicz, so...}$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that if $W\sim\mathsf{Ber}(p)$ then the probability-generating function of $W$ is
\begin{align}
P_W(s) &= \mathbb E[s^W]\\
&= s^0\cdot\mathbb P(W=0)+s^1\cdot\mathbb P(W=1)\\
&= 1-p+ps.
\end{align}
If $W_1,\ldots,W_n$ are independent random variables with probability-generating functions $P_{W_i}(s)$ then the probability-generating function of $\sum_{i=1}^n W_i$ is $\prod_{i=1}^n P_{W_i}(s)$ (this can readily be shown by induction). Since a $\mathsf{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable has the distribution of the sum of $n$ i.i.d. $\mathsf{Ber}(p)$ random variables, it follows that
\begin{align}
P_X(s) &= (1-p + ps)^m\\
P_Y(s) &= (1-p + ps)^n.
\end{align}
It is clear then that the probability-generating function of $X+Y$ is
$$
P_{X+Y}(s) = P_X(s)P_Y(s) = (1-p + ps)^m(1-p + ps)^n = (1-p + ps)^{m+n},
$$
and hence $X+Y$ has $\mathsf{Bin}(m+n,p)$ distribution.